# C# Regular Expression and Replace on part of the match

Tags: c#, regex, string

So I have a regular expression that will look into a string and match all of the relative anchor links, like:
[Leaderboard](/leaderboard)

It will not match where the href starts with HTTP or HTTPS.

Expression is:

```
<a.*?href="([^http]|[^https]).*?"[^<]
```

That part is good for now.

However, I cannot seem to figure out that after I get the match I want to replace just the href name with routerLink.

This:

```
<a href="/leaderboard">Leaderboard</a>
```

Becomes:

```
<a routerLink="/leaderboard">Leaderboard</a>
```

Note href is now routerLink.

There are 20+ matches so I can't simply do a replace with Leaderboard I need to keep the relative path the same.   Literally the only thing in the matched string that gets replaced is href for routerLink and the value of that attribute stays as is.

This part is giving me issue!

Any ideas here?

Thanks

Comment: Use string.Replace("href=","routerLink=");

Comment: Your regex is very peculiar and doesn't really do what you think.

Comment: Just updated my expression.  It had been formatted.  If that is wrong I can create a post just for that one and update you with the link.

Comment: It is still very wrong. I will explain in my answer.

Comment: @JordanMcDonald Any specific reason to parse an html with regex?

Comment: @L.B I just have a string of HTML I get from a service and I need to modify it before it gets rendered on the client side.  Any better ideas?

Comment: @JordanMcDonald you can use  *HtmlAgilityPack*. Seems like you haven't read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @L.B Thanks I am looking into this now as possible better solution.  Thanks for the good looking out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern doesn't do what you think - see what happens if you have `href="halfway"` with your pattern. The pattern you have says
`<a.*?href="([^http]|[^https]).*?"[^<]` which breaks down as:

1. Find the characters `<a` literally.
2. Optionally skip as few characters as possible `.*?` to match
3. Match the characters `href="` literally
4. Accept either a character that is not one of `h`, `t`, `t`, `p` or not one of `h`, `t`, `t`, `p`, `s`. `([^http]|[^https])` - note that character lists in square brackets `[`,`]` represent one character matched.
5. Optionally skip as few characters as possible `.*?` to match
6. Match the character `"` literally
7. Match a character that is not `<`

While this online site won't handle all of .Net regular expressions, it shows the issues and explains how some of the matching operations work: https://regex101.com/r/raoCcA/1

This should work:

```
var pattern = @"href=(?=""(?!http|https))";

var ans = Regex.Replace(src, pattern, "routerLink=");
```

You can try to restrict to `href` inside `a` tags if necessary, but it starts to get too complicated for regular expressions:

```
var pattern = @"(?<=<a([^<>]|<!--|-->)+)href=(?=""(?!http|https))";
```

Comment: Just saw this.  Will test this out.

Comment: With your new pattern you appear to be trying to limit to replacing `href` in `a` tags - is that correct?

Comment: I have a bunch of <a> tags and I only want the ones that do not contain HTTP or HTTPS in the href value.  So really only I want relative paths to match like <a href="/foo">foo</a>

Comment: But do you care about href in other contexts e.g. HTML comments (`<!-- href="was this" -->` or in body text `<p>see href="test" as an example</p>`)?

Comment: That is a good call.  didn't really think of it.  Don't think it will be an issue.  What you gave me above is working.  Do you want me to create a new post to get a more solid and safe Regex?  I only care about <a> tags.  No other tags need to be matched.

Comment: I added an expression that attempts to include only `a` tags. It probably isn't possible to create a regular expression to handle all of HTML5 conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Eventhough other post is already *accepted*, I want to post [an alternative](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) without regex

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

foreach(var a in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
    var href = a.Attributes["href"];
    href.Remove();
    a.Attributes.Add("routerLink", href.Value);
}

var newHtml = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

A Linq query can also be used for the same *XPath*

```
foreach (var a in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
                     .Where(a => a.Attributes["href"] != null))
```

Comment: Yes that is very clean.   Thank you

Comment: Your method is nice but you aren't filtering on only the relative href links, are you?